# Incron Job creating multiple Files

Tags: linux, incron

I am using RedHat (rhelsvrbase64-6.2) version.
    I have written an incron job to convert a file(i.e. in utf-16le format) to UTF-8 Format.

```
When i am running my job, It is creating multiple UTF-8 copies of my file.

    My incrontab script is as follows: 

    **/home/sap/SRMArchive/incronTest IN_CLOSE_WRITE /usr/local/bin/test.sh $@ $#**

    test.sh

    **#!/bin/bash
    echo "hi">>/var/log/my.log
    echo $1>>/var/log/my.log
    echo $2>>/var/log/my.log
    file -bi $1/$2 >>/var/log/my.log
    iconv -f utf-16le -t UTF-8 $1/$2 > $1/UTF8_$2** 

    When i am dropping any file to my '/home/sap/SRMArchive/incronTest' folder, The output i am getting is number of files named as follows :

    UTF8_myFile.txt
    UTF8_UTF8_myFile.txt
    UTF8_UTF8_UTF8_myFile.txt 
    UTF8_UTF8_UTF8_UTF8_myFile.txt
    .........
    ........


Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
    iconv -f utf-16le -t UTF-8 $1/$2 > $1/UTF8_$2**
```

You are creating your output in the same directory you're watching with `incron`.  When `iconv` finishes writing the file, you get a new `IN_CLOSE_WRITE` event, which triggers your script with the name of the output file...and so forth.

In theory, you should get an infinite loop out of this.

The solution is either (a) to generate your output in a different directory, or (b) have your script ignore events on files that begin with `UTF8_`.